# Relación entre tablas (BD)

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, relaciones

Tengo la siguiente información de dos tablas (**Categorías** y **Subcategorías**)

[image: Datos de la tabla Categorías y Subcategorías]

Nótese que en la tabla **Subcategorías** la **Subcategoría 1** se repite en dos Categorías; en la Categoría A y en la Categoría B.
Mi pregunta es, a la hora de relacionar las dos tablas, y de registrar los datos en la BBDD, ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo?

En un principio, consideré relacionar las dos tablas directamente, con un campo foráneo en la tabla de Subcategorías, y registrar la subcategoría que se repite en la BD pero en formato JSON, así de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero luego pensé en tener una tabla detalle de por medio, que me permita relacionar las dos tablas... La cuestión es que como sólo hay una sola Subcategoría que se repite (la subcategoría 1), no sé si amerite y valga la pena una tabla detalle para relacionar las tablas Categorías y Subcategorías; y tampoco sé si almacenar IDs de otra entidad en formato JSON sea la mejor opción...

¿De qué manera lo puedo hacer mejor?

Muchas gracias a cualquier ayuda y sugerencia.

Comment: Depende de lo que sea más importante para ti en éste momento: ¿Escalabilidad, mantenimiento, tiempo de desarrollo, diseño, desempeño, etc.? Y ya después vendrán los arrepentimientos -o alivios-.

Comment: Bueno, creo que por ahora lo más importante es la escalabilidad, mantenimiento y diseño...
Pero independientemente de lo que sea más importante, creo que debe haber una sóla manera correcta de hacerlo... ¿cuál es la más efectiva?

Comment: Esto esta basado en opiniones.. pero porque queres desnormalizar una tabla guardando en un campo un json? guarda dos registros y sacate los problemas de encima. Si el nombre de la subcategoria debe ser normalizado, entonces si hace una tabla intermedia...

Comment: Sí, pero se supone que se debe evitar redundancia.. Es uno de los principios de las Bases de Datos...
La cuestión con la tabla intermedia es que, para registrar una subcategoría en la tabla intermedia, ya debe de estar registrada en la tabla subcategorías.. ¿y el campo foráneo a qué se relacionaría..?